# How can we pass dynamic port names in django .env files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to pass dynamic port names to the .env file variables in django . So that instead of passing port number again and again , I will just pass the variable name to the url.Here is .env code for which i am looking for

```
Xyz_port = 8000
xyz_url = http://192.168.1.39:{Xyz_port}
```

The current code is like that:

```
Xyz_port = 8000
xyz_url = http://192.168.1.39:8000
```

Comment: What are you using to bring in the .env file? E.g. [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv) uses POSIX variable expansion.

Comment: No , I am not using some other package, os.environ.get('variable').

Comment: That's how you get the values out of the environment, but *what's putting them there* from the .env file?

Comment: we are using docker-compose file here to get the values access from the .env file

Comment: So https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/? Could you put that info (and maybe a relevant tag) in the question?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this in the Django project then you can use [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/).

**.env** now looks like

> Xyz_port=8000

**You can use above in any app inside the Django app by adding few codes like below:**

```py
from decouple import config

port = config('Xyz_port')
xyz_url = f'http://192.168.1.39:{port}'
```

Hope this is the answer you are expecting.